xcolor Error: No driver specified
Any ideas why I might get the following problem.
(/home/bard/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/home/bard/contrib/pgf-tikz-3.1.10/doc/color.cfg)

! Package xcolor Error: No driver specified.

See the xcolor package documentation for explanation.

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>    = triangle 45,
      font = \sffamily,
      scale= 2]
    \path ( 0,  0) node (X) {x}
        ++(-1, -2) node (Y) {y}
        ++( 1, -2) node (U) {u}
        ++( 1,  2) node (Z) {z};

    \begin{scope}[semithick, ->, every node/.style = {below,sloped}]
      \draw (X) -- (Y);
      \draw (X) -- (Z);
      \draw (Y) -- node {*} (U);
      \draw (Z) -- node {*} (U);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}


  \caption[Short Title]{Test.}
  \label{fig:Fhlbrt-ff}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


you have a non standard color config file contrib/pgf-tikz-3.1.10/doc/color.cfg that is breaking latex color support, you should remove that and report an issue to wherever you got that file from

pgf has a local color.cfg in its documentation tree but that should never be in the main input tree, how come you are using a non standard pgf installation rather than the one that came with your texlive?

I thought to use the most recent version because I have an old texlive.

that is almost certainly a bad idea. new packages are not guaranteed to work on old tex systems you should use the package that comes with your system. but if you do install a newer package (which might sometimes be needed) don't break latex by installing files not intended to be installed in the tex input path, such as the doc tree in this case

So I go ahead and remove the file ?

move the entire /home/bard/contrib/pgf-tikz-3.1.10/doc tree (or preferably the whole of /home/bard/contrib/pgf-tikz-3.1.10)

I’m voting to close this question because it is caused by misconfiguration unlikely to be found on other systems.
